# Why is my cursor in a random far-away place in Visual Studio Debug Console

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console, console-application

[screenshot of debugging cursor randomly below everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VponL.png)

Every time I go to debug, I have to scroll up. The cursor is lost in the middle of nowhere, the same place every time, and regardless of project.

I can't find anything similar online. My code isn't moving the cursor.